# Opening a Web UI for a service running on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dart-webui

I am trying to run a local instance of Solr in my Amazon EC2 instance and I want to know how to open the Admin UI for Solr

I tried < public IP >:8983/solr and it is not working. I am kinda new to AWS and want to know if there is a way.

Instance Details:

EC2 -  Ubuntu Server t2.micro

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the below Security group rule to your EC2 security group.

[image]

And then in browser type `< public IP >:8983/solr/admin/` And it will show up.

Comment: This means everybody in the world can connect to that instance...